# SQL Server - Querying DateTime stored as string

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have an existing database that was setup (for whatever reason??) to store a date time as a string. I need to run a query for records that where entered between a specific date range but am not having any luck.

The string field is formatted like `1/25/2007 - 4:39 PM`. I have tried the query below but of course it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT ID, CUSTOMER, ADD1, ADDZ, CITY, STATE, LASTD, ORDNUM
FROM dcar
WHERE  (STATE = N'OR') AND (CAST(dcar.LASTD AS datetime) BETWEEN convert(smalldatetime, '10/01/2011', 101) AND convert(smalldatetime, '10/31/2011', 101))
```

PS - I have no idea why the developer decided to store dates this way!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to cast the field as a datetime, if you remove the dash between the date and time with the `REPLACE` function like so:

```
SELECT ID, CUSTOMER, ADD1, ADDZ, CITY, STATE, LASTD, ORDNUM
FROM dcar
WHERE  (STATE = N'OR') AND
CAST(REPLACE(dcar.LASTD, ' -', '') AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '10/01/2011' AND '10/31/2011'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not really using the time part of the value stored. If so, this may work for you:

Use the string manipulation functions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) to extract the date part of the string and then use convert() to convert that to a datetime. You could, for example, use CHARINDEX() to find the index of the "-" and then use SUBSTRING() to get the characters up to that point. Then use convert, passing in the appropriate style value as documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx.